# Flex 2 and Flex 3 module interop

Tags: apache-flex

I have an application built on Flex 2. I am writing a new application (module based) in Flex 3. Will these be able to co-exist? Can I invoke Flex 3 module from Flex 2 application?

Anyone have tried this before?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alex Harui from Adobe SDK Team answered the question on FlexCoders Yahoo Group.

Alex - "All modules and the SWFs that load them must be using the same version of the SDK."

I had a follow-up question - "Are there any other options to make applications built using different versions of Flex SDK work together? Can Mosaic or any other product/technology help?"

Alex "He replied "Mosaic or any other Marshall Plan topology allows for mixing versions, but not with any code prior to 3.2.  Why do you need to create a new module in Flex 3?"